# Why does my Google Translate API work in the terminal but not an executable?

Tags: python, module, executable, importerror, google-translate

I can import and run Google Translate API in a Python shell in the terminal:

```
>>> from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
>>> translate
<module 'google.cloud.translate_v2' from '/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v2/__init__.py'>
```

But the same statement gives an error when I run it from a script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/bin/tranzlate", line 7, in <module>
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

What explains the difference? And what must I do to run it from a script?

Further to comments by user1558604 + jason m:

When running the following statements:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

... the terminal reports:

> /home/anaconda3/bin/python

... while the executable reports:

> /usr/bin/python

As you can see, I'm running Anaconda. When I installed the Google Translate module, I did so with the command:

```
pip install google-cloud-translate==2.0.0
```

Also:

```
$ which pip
/home/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

And:

```
$ whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/share/python /home/anaconda3/bin/python /home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m-config /home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7-config /home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m /home/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Then also:

```
$ which python
/home/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: Add "import sys;print(sys.executable)". Run it both ways. Do you get the same output?

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? If not, get Conda set up ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had two installations of python, one made with Anaconda. When I installed the Google Cloud API module, I did it within the conda environment, using pip.

Now when I invoke python from a terminal, it opens the conda version. When I invoke it in a bash script with the usual `#!/usr/bin/python` shebang, it opens the regular version. And then it fails to find the Google Cloud API module, because its installed only in the conda environment.

The obvious fix is replace the script's Python shebang with one pointing to the Anaconda version. The path is given by the shell command:

```
$ which python
/home/anaconda3/bin/python
```

If I invoke Python in a script with the shebang '#!/home/anaconda3/bin/python'. Python finds the Google API if I invoke it this way. But the script fails for other reasons. I had forgotten this, but the version of Python installed at `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2. Anaconda is running Python 3. I had forgotten this. The code was not quite portable. Using the Anaconda shebang creates another niggling problem: my text editor (gedit) no longer does recognises that its Python, so does not set syntax highlighting automatically.

My quick fix was to deactivate the conda environment and install the Google API in the version of python installed in the base environment (the actual base, system environment, that is - not the base conda environment), where Python 2 is installed, at `/usr/bin/python`.

```
$ conda deactivate
$ sudo apt install python-pip
$ pip install google-cloud-translate==2.0.0
```

The Google API documentation, incidentally, recommends installing it in a virtual environment, thus:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-python
```

It seems now from experience, that might have been wise. Though the reasons for avoiding doing so were similar to the reasons for installing Python 2 in the base environment - to perform some pressing task immediately, without having to stop and learn about environments. Conda is running as the 'base' environment because it sets itself up that way. It was installed in the first place not as the result of an educated decision to set up a conda environment, but because some hurried reading at a time when one has least time of all - when upgrading the base (linux) system - implied that a conda Linux distribution might be convenient.

Comment: You say to deactivate the Conda env, but aren’t you using virtualenv?